# Equivalent WAL retention to the same wal_keep_segments varies a lot

Tags: postgresql

We use postgresql 10 and use `pg_basebackup --pgdata=- -X fetch --format=tar` to backup.
Depends on our database size the backup may take many hours.
So we check how long our backup took and what's the equivalent WAL retention of our `wal_keep_segments` param by running `SELECT max(modification)-min(modification) FROM pg_ls_waldir()`.

However equivalent WAL retention for the same `wal_keep_segments` varies a lot, while the WAL retention drops too low, our backup failed due to WAL segments were removed.

```
pg_basebackup: could not get write-ahead log end position from server:
ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010001DDE200000034 has already been removed
```

Is there a way to configure WAL retention directly instead of the number of WAL segments? Also what may cause this issue?

Here is a graph for WAL retention of our databases. Some step increase were due to increase wall_keep_segments, but the waving pattern is not.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use `--wal-method=stream` instead of `--wal-method=fetch`. This is actually enabled since PostgreSQL 10 by default.

```
pg_basebackup --format=tar --wal-method=stream --gzip --compress=9 --pgdata=.
```

You'd get 2 files in the output directory - base.tar.gz and pg_wal.tar.gz. But you will loose ability to use a better compression program or easily pipe the data over the network.

Alternatively you can disable wal archiving in the backup and actually archive all wal files with `archive_command`. You'd need to setup a corresponding `restore_command` for `recovery.conf` while restoring a backup. This would also allow you to use point-in-time recovery which can prove very useful.